# search data export from local.ch

Tags: c#, asp.net, search-engine

I want to export data from "local.ch" site.

what type of method i can use for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
static string GetContent()
{
url = 'http://local.ch';
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", 
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
data.Close();
reader.Close();
return s;
}
```

quoted from http://www.charlesrcook.com/archive/2008/11/15/pulling-web-content-with-c.aspx

Comment: it will just read page source. but i want get just only search result and export to excel file.

Comment: yeh, was being half sarcastic. your going to have to implement some sort of wget or curl, send the correct post parameters matching the search form or whathave you. (view the html source for these variables, and the documentation from your library on how to implement a post request). the response from the post ideally will be the result, which you can then parse with some sort of dom parser. If you really want, I can extend my answer to explain these steps in better detail, probably wouldn't be terrible to put into the knowledge base or anything.

Comment: yaa please explain in detail. so i can understand easily. or any ready library.

Comment: this page http://en.csharp-online.net/HTTP_Post actually gives code to post in c#! The ready library is System.Net